# Best way to give user support in Android market

Tags: android

I'm near to launch my first app in the android market. I want to give users the posibility to say which things like, dislike or where are problems... which is the best way? Email? Blog? GoogleGroups? Google Code ( my code isn't opensource )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently discovered [littlegreenbugs.com](http://littlegreenbugs.com/) but haven't used it in earnest yet for my app. It automatically creates a page for each app on the market, so my app was already on there with no setup required on my part. I just had to claim it.

It is a little simplistic, but maybe this would make it more accessible to users.

So far I've just been using email, which has been adequate, but I'm losing track of which are the most popular feature requests. I've had about 40 emails from ~70,000 installs, in case that's useful. (It's a free app, so users probably don't feel very entitled to support.)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a basic forum with sections for bug reports, enhancement requests and so on. If you did that you might have to commit a substantial amount of time to monitoring it and responding to posts on it so that might not be the way to go if you expect a lot of people to provide feedback and you don't have much time.

Comment: This, but start slowly and grow as your userbase does. Maybe people won't have very many questions or comments and a simple email address will suffice. Once the email starts overflowing, set up a forum/blog/group.

Answer (score 0):

In our latest app the actual best thing we have done to get instant user feedback is to use a chatserver. We use openFire for the server and then implemented [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) in the app. Be sure to log every suggestion and such.

We also use a forum but it is not as active as the chat. But a forum is also a really good idea.